# How to build a text classification model based on a non categorical target?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset with two text columns and I should build a prediction model for a float column containing a probability value (a number between 0 and 1). My difficult here is to handle the target column. Every method and example that I find are for categorical target columns, with a short range of possibilities. But in my case, my target column doesn't work in that way.

I already got some results using another numeric columns of the dataset and linear regression, but linear regression doesn't work with text features. I also tried to implement naive bayes, but I got stuck with the non categorical target.

Comment: You can try feature extraction from text methods, Like bag of words, tf-idf etc. . Here is some documentation about it : http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html

Comment: Using naive bayes and tfidf I got to predict the product category (a categorical attribute) through the title (a text attribute). But I can't use the same code for the target column because it's a float non categorical. Again, I'm stucked.

Comment: The data and targets are two different things. If the targets are discrete, then its classification and if the targets are continuous (real numbers), then its a regression problem. The data will be needed to convert to numbers no matter what your targets are. So maybe you need a regression model. Start with scikit classes having `Regressor` at their end. Or explain more clearly with data samples and code about what you want to do.

Comment: @VivekKumar My dataset have several numeric features, and some text columns that I used LabelEncoder successfully. I already got some results using linear regression with this. Despite that, the dataset have 2 text columns (title and description) that aren't encodable. Using naive bayes and tf-idf I got to predict the product caterory using the title with a decent accuracy. But the category is discrete, and my target is continuous, so I imagine that naive bayes won't help in this case. I did read something about logistic regression to solve text classification, but couldn't get it implemented.

Comment: I am sorry, but you are not making any sense. You can combine the text and categorical data into a single array. You say your targets are continuous and in then say you are working on classification problem. If the targets are continous then its a regression. But LogisticRegression (dont go on name) is a classifier. It wont help you. You said you tried LinearRegression. Thats the way to go. Show some samples of your data (all your features, categorical, numerical and text features) and we can code to combine that into single array. Leave the targets out.